# Coverting single page tiff images to multipage tiff images in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some single page tiff images and just want to convert it into multipage tiff images. Is there any plugin avialable in ruby or in rails?

Answer (score 0):

by using rmagick

system("convert #{image} -adjoin #{@first_image_name}")

For Ref visit:http://senthiljruby.posterous.com/combining-single-tiff-into-multiple-tiff-imag